# HTML5 drag and drop - Only on item per dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have some divs as dropzones and some as draggable objects.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="drop"></div>
   <div class="drop"></div>
   <div class="drop"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="drag" id="drag-a" draggable="true">box a</div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-b" draggable="true">box b</div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-c" draggable="true">box c</div>
</div>
<style>
.drop {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
.drag {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.drop').on('dragover', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.drag').on('dragstart', function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', e.target.id);
    });
    $('.drop').on('drop', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');  
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    });
});
</script>
```

With native HTML5 drag and drop and jQuery that works fine. Now I want to restrict the dropzones to one item. It should not be possible to drop another one to this zone but I don't know how.

Is it possible that the two draggable boxes exchange their positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the event handler for that element, in jQuery you can do it with [`.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```
$('.drop').on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');  
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    // add this line
    $(this).off('dragover drop');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.drop').on('dragover', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.drag').on('dragstart', function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', e.target.id);
    });
    $('.drop').on('drop', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');  
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        $(this).off('dragover drop');
    });
});
```

```css
.drop {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
.drag {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="drop"></div>
   <div class="drop"></div>
   <div class="drop"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="drag" id="drag-a" draggable="true">box a</div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-b" draggable="true">box b</div>
    <div class="drag" id="drag-c" draggable="true">box c</div>
</div>
```

### Restarting the drag&drop functionality

Even when you limit each dropzone to just one box, is a common case to allow the user to remove the dropped box and to drop a different one.

First, you should convert your anonymous function handlers in named function declarations, to be able to reuse them.

Then, allow the box container to accept drag&drop operations.

Last, when the user drops a box in the container, add again handlers for the `drop` and `dragover` events in whatever empty dropzone.

Note: This time, I have modified a little the name of the classes to make it more clear.

```js
var dragOverHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};
var dropOnDropZoneHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  $(this).off('dragover drop');
};
var dropOnBoxContainerHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  $('.dropzone').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
      $(this).on('dragover', dragOverHandler);
      $(this).on('drop', dropOnDropZoneHandler);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', e.target.id);
  });
  $('.dropzone, #boxContainer').on('dragover', dragOverHandler);
  $('.dropzone').on('drop', dropOnDropZoneHandler);
  $('#boxContainer').on('drop', dropOnBoxContainerHandler);
});
```

```css
.dropzone, #boxContainer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}

#boxContainer {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
</div>
<div id="boxContainer">
  <div class="box" id="drag-a" draggable="true">box a</div>
  <div class="box" id="drag-b" draggable="true">box b</div>
  <div class="box" id="drag-c" draggable="true">box c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. Is it possible to start that drag/dragover again?